# size of a number in the checkbox label

Tags: html, angularjs

My checkbox label title is : `Remettre les montants à 0`
but `0` appears  like an `o`

`Remettre les montants à 0`(html) becomes `Remettre les montants à o` (browser)

I can't make all the label uppercase

Here is my code:

html :

```html
<label class="ral-med-12 space-bottom15" style="display: block">
    <input style="margin:0 10px;vertical-align:middle;" type="checkbox" ng-model="data.montants" name="pre"/>Remettre les montants à 0 ? 
</label>
```

the number "0" in this sentence appears in the browser very small like " Remettre les montants à o"

any help please ,
thanks

Comment: can you please explain a bit more L.E?

Comment: html : <label class="ral-med-12 space-bottom15" style="display: block" ><input style="margin:0 10px;vertical-align:middle;" type="checkbox" ng-model="data.montants" name="pre"/>Remettre les montants  à 0 ? </label>      the number "0" in this sentence appears in the browser very small like " Remettre les montants  à o"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you just want to clearly show the difference between a `0`[zero] and `o`[the letter o].

It's rather specific to the font you're using buddy.

What I'd suggest is use a different font altogether that differentiates between such characters, or you could use the different font for specifically those characters.

Font can be changed by setting the `style` attribute as: `style="font-family:consolas;`

**Consolas** is one font that clearly differentiates `0`[zero] from the letter "o", as zero has a slash across it.

Either show the entire line with the new font like:

```html
<label class="ral-med-12 space-bottom15" style="display: block">
    <input style="margin:0 10px;vertical-align:middle;" type="checkbox" ng-model="data.montants" name="pre"/> <span style="font-family:consolas;">This is ZERO ==>0<br/> And this is the letter O[UpperCase] and o[lowerCase]</span> 
</label>
```

Or just the specific text:

```html
<label class="ral-med-12 space-bottom15" style="display: block">
    <input style="margin:0 10px;vertical-align:middle;" type="checkbox" ng-model="data.montants" name="pre"/> This is ZERO ==> <span style="font-family:consolas;">0</span><br/> And these are letters of the alphabet ==> <span style="font-family:consolas;"> O[UpperCase] and o[lowerCase]</span> 
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike"> I HAVE A BIKE<br>
 or by 
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">I HAVE A BIKE</label>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cool_ashwin/kbmfvxwc/2/)

Comment: i think you have not got me , what i want is instead of "Remettre les montants à o" i wanna have "Remettre les montants à 0" it's like the "0" in the html  appears like an "o" in the browser that's all

Comment: Thanks Sir, to Explain, for that you can use the different  font family, different font family  easily available on google fonts, like open sans and other, hope this will solve the issue